# Incompatible with sql_mode 'only_full_group_by' but it's not set

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run a query but I am getting the following error:

> SQL Error (1055): Expression #14 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'gamesmart.gps.plays' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

When I check my `sql_mode` it is set to the following for both `session` and `global`:

[image: sql_mode]

So, why is it still giving me this error?

Mysql Version: 5.7.14

Comment: And where's the query?

Answer (score 2):

Try to resolve the Query due to 5.7 Requirements:

- disable 'only_full_group_by' by setting your sql_mode.  NOT
     RECOMMENDED!
- rewrite your query either by setting the appropriate
   column name in der group by list
- Set ANY_VALUE(fieldname) within
  your SELECT query if your really know that this is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options that I found that worked (I was able to do one or the other):

- convert all the aggregate functions from something like this `ifnull(gps.plays,0)` to this `ifnull(gps.plays,0) as plays` in the select clause.
- in the `.ini` file set the following:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal:

```
mysql -u yourusername -p
```

Then type your password. It will bring you to the MySQL monitor.

Write this query:

```
set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

After that, go to etc/mysql/my.cnf, open the file, and paste the code below the line.

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

It worked for me.